# tn.read_until is not working

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying telnet to a remote client using following code (will the variables declared).

```
tn = telnetlib.Telnet(host)
tn.read_until("login: ")
tn.write(user + "\n")
tn.read_until("Password: ")
tn.write(password + "\n")
```

But I noticed that code is getting stuck tn.read_until("login: ").
I verified it by adding a timeout .. and it times out.

Telnet ports are open and I am opening the telnet connection using putty.

I have tried it in 2.7 & 3.4 .. it is behaving the same.

Comment: I might be useful to drop the first letter in your `read_until()` command. i know this results in your code saying `read_until('assword')` but sometimes telnet read commands work funny, especially when you're looking for something specific. the less specific the matching you have to do, the better.

Comment: Thanks Jiynx.. Bang on the target .. read_until("ogin :") worked fine..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure your baudrates between your remote connection and your 'terminal' are matching. that can make for funky reads.

You will also want to pass your write commands with encoding. Especially so in python 3.x as strings are encoded as utf-8, and this needs to be translated. You can pass it as a bytestring:

```
tn.write(b'username\n')
```

Or by encoding the user variable itself when you create it:

```
user = 'username\n'.encode('ascii')
```

Or when you call the variable(if you do the above without using the `.encode()` addition:

```
tn.write(user.encode('ascii')
```

Telnetlib is kind of dumb that way, as it simply spits the command to the buffer as-is. You the user have to ensure that it's in a format that's usable on the other end.

One thing you can do to test that you're properly passing command is to do a `print(tn.read_very_eager())` after your username write command and see what has been passed to the buffer.